# How many 5 letter words can be formed from the word management if two alike letters are always together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many 5 letter words can be formed from the word MANAGEMENT if two alike letters are always together?

My approach was like this:

The letters M, N, A , E appear twice and G, T appear once.

So, the first case was where all the letters were different, thus, the number of words formed were:

## **<sup>6</sup>C5 . 5!(further permutation) = 720**

the second case was where there were two groups of two alike letters and one different letter.
Thus, the number of words formed were:

## <sup>2</sup>C<sub>1</sub> . <sup>4</sup>C<sub>2</sub> . 3! = 72

the third case was where there were one group of two alike letters and three different letters.

Thus, the number of words formed were:

## <sup>4</sup>C<sub>1</sub> . <sup>5</sup>C3 . 4!= 960

thus, the total number of words were:

## 720 + 72 + 960 = 1752

but this answer is wrong as the Real answer is 1824.

Where was I wrong? Please explain.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  The mistake was in the case in which there are two double letters and a single letter.  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of choosing two double letters since there are four letters that appear twice in the word $MANAGEMENT$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I spent a lot of time on that part, but still missed a very simple thing. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 double letters: M,N,A,E and 2 single letters G,T.

To form 5 letter words in which two letters alike are together, there are possibilities as follows:

- the 5-letter word contains only single letters: $\binom{6}{5} \times 5!$
- the 5-letter word contains 1 double letters and 3 single letters: $\binom{4}{1} \times \binom{5}{3} \times 4!$
- the 5-letter word contains 2 double letters and 1 single letter: $\binom{4}{2} \times \binom{4}{1} \times 3!$

Total give you 1824.

Comment: You should say $4$ double letters and $2$ single letters.  Also, you should write the $5$-letter word contains only single letters (and, similarly, for the remaining cases).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your only mistake was the case in which there are two double letters and a single letter.  As you observed, the four letters $M$, $N$, $A$, $E$ each appear twice.  We must select two of them to be the double letters, which we can do in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  Since there are six distinct letters in the word $MANAGEMENT$, whichever two we choose to use as the double letters, there four distinct letters left from which to choose the remaining letter, which we can do in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.  We now have three objects to permute, the two double letters and the other letter we selected, which we can do in $3!$ ways.  Hence, in this case, there are 
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1}3! = 144$$
possible arrangements.

Notice that $$6! + \binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{3}4! + \binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1}3! = 720 + 960 + 144 = 1824$$

Answer (score 1):

The miscalculation is here:

> the second case was where there were two groups of two alike letters and one different letter. Thus, the number of words formed were: 
>   **<sup>2</sup>C<sub>1</sub> . <sup>4</sup>C<sub>2</sub> . 3! = 72**

I assume your ${2\choose 1}$ implies you are choosing from $G$ and $T$ and ${4\choose 2}$ implies you are choosing 2 letters from $M,N,A,E$. Your ${4\choose 2}$ is correct, since you will get two groups of two alike letters, consequently total $4$ letters. However, your ${2\choose 1}$ is not correct (it must be ${4\choose 1}$), because you can choose not only from $G$ and $T$, but also from the remaining two letters of $M,N,A,E$. Because, a single letter will be a different (unlike) letter.

All the rest is fine.